# Animate UIView subclass with curveEaseOut

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a custom drawn progress bar that I am looking to animate in a more smooth manner than the options available with transition. But it doesn't respond to `.curveEaseOut` like I have below. If I changed it to `.transitionCrossDissolve` it would work but I'd prefer the curve animation. How can I get this to work?

```
@IBOutlet var experienceProgress: experienceBar!

func updateProgress() {
    experienceProgress.progress = 0.5

    experienceProgress.setNeedsDisplay()

    UIView.transition(with: experienceProgress, 
                      duration: 1.25, 
                      options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, 
                      animations: {
        self.experienceProgress.layer.displayIfNeeded()
    })
}

@IBDesignable
class experienceBar: UIView {

    var progress:CGFloat = 0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 0, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1.000)

        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: progress * 132, height: 8.5))
        color.setFill()
        rectanglePath.fill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that your `draw(_:)` is a snapshot of the view at a given time, so it’s not easily animatable. To animate `UIView` objects, it’s always easiest if you can use animatable properties. As the `UIView` [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview):

> Changes to several view properties can be animated—that is, changing the property creates an animation starting at the current value and ending at the new value that you specify. The following properties of the `UIView` class are animatable:
>
> - `frame`
> - `bounds`
> - `center`
> - `transform`
> - `alpha`
> - `backgroundColor`

Technically, you theoretically could do your own manual animation, but it’s often best to first see if you can refactor the code to use one of these `UIView` animatable properties.

Fortunately, in this case, you can eliminate your `draw(_:)` and replace that with something that uses subviews where you can animate the `frame` (which is an animatable property) of the subview reflecting the “percent complete” portion.

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomProgressView: UIView {
    public var progress: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { updateProgress() } }

    private var progressView: UIView = {
        let progressView = UIView()
        progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 0, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)
        return progressView
    }()

    override public init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateProgress()
    }

    override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        progress = 0.5
    }
}

private extension CustomProgressView {
    func configure() {
        addSubview(progressView)
    }

    func updateProgress() {
        var rect = bounds
        rect.size.width *= progress

        progressView.frame = rect
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.progressView.progress = 0.75
}, completion: nil)
```

---

A couple of unrelated observations:

1. I didn’t quite get the intent of the `progress * 132`. So I just assumed that the `progress` was a percentage between 0.0 and 1.0, and that the subview would go that percentage across.
2. I made the updating of the subview happen automatically in the `didSet` of the `progress` property. The view controller (or whatever) should never have to manually say `setNeedsDisplay` or anything like that.
3. I changed the class name to start with an uppercase letter. Variables and method names start with lowercase letter, but type names (like classes, structs, enums, etc.), always start with uppercase letter.
4. I notice you made this `@IBDesignable`. If so, it’s often nice to have `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` set the value to something interesting so you can see the progress view better in IB.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer and helpful tips! This works exactly the way I wanted.